# How do I get a website id from a store id?

Tags: magento-1, stores, programming

Given a store id, how do I get the website id that matches that store?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Like this:

```
Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId)->getWebsiteId()
```

Or do a direct database lookup on the core_store table.

Answer (score 14):

Just for completeness: From the current store you're in, you could retrieve the websiteId as follows:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
```

Answer (score 6):

In Magento 2 to you can find the Website Id using store id like this:

> $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeID)->getWebsiteId();

Comment: Magento 1 Inside the phtml file how to get website id? thanks @Faisal Sheikh

Comment: @Gem Do you want current website id or all website ids?

Comment: My condition :  if website_id == 2 { hello} else { hi }

Comment: I just want to put inside my app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html

Comment: My Code: https://paste.ofcode.org/GKsBaztggNpXrmSws7cEyG line 30 - 40

Comment: @Gem your code: $website_id = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId(); is correct, please print this result.

Comment: @Gem If you still having the problem, so please use this code: $websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId(); to get the current website id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105641/discussion-between-gem-and-faisal-sheikh).

Comment: @Gem Did you used this code: $websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId();  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have database access you can directly check website id in store_website table